# Low Quality Post review doesn't show the content when completed with Edit

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

I recently reviewed [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/215854/58193) over on SFF in the Low Quality Posts queue. It didn't warrant closure and could do with a small edit so naturally I clicked Edit, did what I needed to do and moved on. Going back through my review history though and navigating to [that particular review](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/150560) I am met with this:

[image: Screenshot of the review in question]

As you can see the body of the review is completely missing and the question is not shown. I did also [review the First Post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/150558) for it but the question body is shown there.

Is this a bug and if so can it be fixed?

---

Looking on a previous [Low Quality Posts review](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/150404) I edited on and the review is shown though it was an answer. Further this [LQP](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/149963) again doesn't show anything but [this one does](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/149959).

Also looking at an [Edit Low Quality Post review](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/273612) on Arqade doesn't show anything like the issue here.

It appears as this bug might be affecting questions only and only when Editing from the Low Quality Posts review as the others appear to be fine as far as I can tell.

---

For completeness sake I checked the other types of reviews [Delete](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/150554), [Looks OK](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/150553) and [invalidated](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/150527) and I can see all of them.