# Newest "exact duplicate" isn't showing the duplicate target in the close notice

Tags: bug, closed-questions

Recently [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345904/468333) was closed as duplicate. However, the duplicate target isn't showing in the close banner. It shows:

> **This questions already exists:**
>
> Closed 3 mins ago.

[image]

However, [older questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330760/468333) are showing the target.

Comment: Can't even edit the duplicate list there - gives a 404! Something is definitely off...

Comment: @Shog9 Are you able to edit dupe target list for older questions? For example, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330760/468333)?

Comment: Yep - works fine there. Something busted on the new one.

Comment: This is a known issue when you self-close your own question as the author. See [Closed as a duplicate, but the duplicate list is empty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty)

Comment: Can this please fixed asap. It defeats the whole duplicate system at the SE sites.