# Target question not shown in duplicate notice on Android Chrome

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, post-notices

My recently closed question isn't showing the duplicate target:

[image]

Other duplicate questions seem to be fine (both mine and others).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newest "exact duplicate" isn't showing the duplicate target in the close notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345907/newest-exact-duplicate-isnt-showing-the-duplicate-target-in-the-close-notice) I reported it here some minutes ago. Same behaviour on Firefox.

Comment: Heh, in that case I won't close this post and leave it to others. :)